# iBatis' ScriptRunner Is Failing To Execute a Perfectly Valid SQL Script

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm using iBatis' ScriptRunner to execute scripts on an Oracle database. The first script is executed fine, but the second one which has triggers in it returns:

```
Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

The part of the script which returns this error is executed without any errors on SQL Developer:

```
.
.
.
create table MG_MSGALR
(
   ID            VARCHAR2(30) not null,
   V_GRAV        VARCHAR2(3),
   constraint PK_MG_MSGALR primary key (ID) using index tablespace B_INDEX
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UC_JAR_LST_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
ON UC_JAR_LST
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT UC_JAR_LST_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UC_UPD_LST_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
ON UC_UPD_LST
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT UC_UPD_LST_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Here's how I execute the script from my side:

```
        Boolean procedure = StringUtils.endsWith(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName()), "procedure") || StringUtils.endsWith(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName()), "trigger");
        runner.setSendFullScript(procedure);
        runner.runScript(new FileReader(file));
```

I noticed that the Boolean procedure's value is always false even when the script has triggers in it, and so I tried to force ScriptRunner to send it as a full script just to see if it goes through or not and i got the following error instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UC_UPD_LST_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
ON UC_UPD_LST
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT UC_UPD_LST_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
END;
/
.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Could somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong here? Should add some sort of delimiter in the file right before when the trigger creation is supposed to start (which is now at the very end of the file).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into the same problem. When you have a hybrid script (which means it has both normal queries and procedures or triggers), and if you're trying to execute it using myBatis from Java, all you need to do is leave all of your procedures at the end of your script and put delimiters before and after them to let SQL know it should be executed as a block and not line by line. So here's how I added my delimiters:

```
-- Change the delimiter to '$'
-- @DELIMITER $

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UC_JAR_LST_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
ON UC_JAR_LST
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT UC_JAR_LST_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
-- Change the delimiter back to ';'
-- @DELIMITER ;
END;

-- Change the delimiter to '$'
-- @DELIMITER $

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UC_UPD_LST_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
ON UC_UPD_LST
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT UC_UPD_LST_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
-- Change the delimiter back to ';'
-- @DELIMITER ; 
END;
```

And the execution ended without errors.